# Как сделать серверную часть для игры unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, сервер

Проблема в том что надо сделать так чтобы игрок только отсылал данные своих действий, а не того что он кого то убил. а сервер сам принял и понял что он кого то убил и отослал это всем.
но не знаю как это вообще делается. есть идея могу запустить 1000 выделенных клиентов на сервере и каждый будет подключаться к игровой комнате и обрабатывать ее. Но тут встанет вопрос производительности.
если непонятно обюяснил то я делаю клон Brawl stars. вот надо чтото примерно такое же как и у них

Comment: Ну скорее всего там всё же один сервер обрабатывает все задачи по разным объектам/комнатам в несколько потоков. Скорее всего если прям на толпу народа считать, то мощности нужны будут соответствующие.